# Mac, how to remap control + HJKL to left, down, up, right, using Karabiner

Tags: mac

I just downloaded Karabiner, but didn't find the remap that I need. So I want to create my own remap rules, but don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Done by myself, easy actually.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<item>
    <name>Ctrl + HJKL to Left/Down/Up/Right</name>
    <identifier>private.ctrl_hjkl</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::H, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::J, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::CURSOR_DOWN</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::K, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::CURSOR_UP</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::L, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT</autogen>
</item>
```

Just past these code to private.xml under folder:

```
/Library/Application Support/Karabiner
```

Done.